# Java readAllBytes from a file removes owner password protection done by PDFBox StandardProtectionPolicy

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have put owner password protection on a pdf doc using PDFBox StandardProtectionPolicy(allow reading not editing),  when I check the saved final document the owner password protection is there but when I read bytes from the saved password protected document it loses all password protection,  cannot understand why...!

My code:

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(inputPdf));
     AccessPermission accessPermission = new AccessPermission();
     accessPermission.setCanModify(false);
     accessPermission.setCanPrint(false); //Disable printing
     accessPermission.setCanExtractContent(false);
     accessPermission.setCanPrintDegraded(false);
     accessPermission.setReadOnly();
     StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy(password, "", accessPermission);
     spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
     pdDocument.protect(spp);
     pdDocument.save(new java.io.File(outputPdf));
     //Close the document
     pdDocument.close();
```

outputPdf is owner password protected as expected,  but readAllbytes removes all protection!

I have also applied file level write protection but no effect:

```
File file = new File(outputPdf);
     //Setting permissions to the file
     file.setReadable(true); //read
     file.setWritable(false); //write
     file.setExecutable(true);
```

Need to return bytes of above file to caller:

```
return Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(outputPdf);
     //removes all owner password protections
```

Appreciate help - how to return bytes without removing protections...?!

Comment: Password protection of a PDF means that the bytes in the file are encrypted, not that they can't be read from the file system.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `readAllBytes`?

Comment: If that 3-liner can 'remove the protections', the 'protections' are obviously completely useless. Either you're right (you're not), or, you've drawn the wrong conclusions (which is what's happening here). Those bytes your final snippet returns? The bytes _themselves_ are encrypted. You can't open those bytes as a PDF. If you can, then you didn't run the first snippet - because you definitely __did not__ save that PDF with protections.

Comment: *"readAllbytes removes all protection!"* - how did you determine that?

Comment: Hi @tgdavies was expecting owner password protection remains intact(bytes are encrypted) so readAllBytes should not allow editing,  but that's not the case  - after readAllyBytes(and sending those to caller) and converting the bytes back into a pdf - it allows editing,  which it should not right...?

Am encrypting pdf with owner password using pdf box code as in my original post - and the file generated out of that is indeed owner password protected,  but readAllBytes and converting bytes back into pdf  that owner password protection is getting lost(and it should not)...!

Answer (score 1):

When I read this first I thought that maybe you had found a bug, but after carefully testing your code I realized you are good. Your code should work. I'm not sure if this is because you probably are using an old version of pdf-box. I'm using this one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I'm quite confident that the document you generated is encoded as it should be.

### Adapting code

I decided to check your code in more detail and made some modifications because `setCanPrintDegraded` doesn't exist in the latest version. I adapted the code you placed and made some modifications to be able to test the whole process individually. This way I divided your code into two segments. One that reads an unprotected pdf file and saves a new protected file, and another that tries to read back from that file and see if we get an error.

This is the first bit where we create the encrypted pdf:

```
public static File createSecretFile(String inputPdf) throws IOException {
    var secretName = getSecretName(inputPdf);
    if(new File(secretName).delete()){
        out.printf("File %s has been deleted! %n",secretName);
    }
    var pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new File(inputPdf));
    var accessPermission = new AccessPermission();
    accessPermission.setCanModify(false);
    accessPermission.setCanPrint(false);
    accessPermission.setCanExtractContent(false);
    accessPermission.setReadOnly();
    var standardProtectionPolicy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("owner", "user", accessPermission);
    standardProtectionPolicy.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
    pdDocument.protect(standardProtectionPolicy);
    var file = new File(secretName);
    pdDocument.save(file);
    pdDocument.close();
    return file;
}
```

And this is the second bit where we try to read the file back:

```
public static void readAndCopySecretFile(String secretDocumentRead) throws IOException {
    var secretReadName = getSecretReadName(secretDocumentRead);
    if(new File(secretReadName).delete()){
        out.printf("File %s has been deleted! %n",secretReadName);
    }
    var pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new File(secretDocumentRead));
    pdDocument.save(new File(secretReadName));
    pdDocument.close();
}
```

### Testing the standard

The standard way of reading is using the `pdf-box` library itself and so for that we can create two tests like this:

```
@Test
void readAndCopySecretFile() {
    var file = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource(TEST_SECRET_PDF)).getFile();
    assertThrowsExactly(InvalidPasswordException.class, () ->
            SecretDocument.readAndCopySecretFile(file)
    );
}

@Test
void createSecretFile() throws IOException {
    var file = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource(TEST_PDF)).getFile();
    File secretFile = SecretDocument.createSecretFile(file);
    System.out.printf("Secret file was created in %s%n", secretFile.getAbsolutePath());
    boolean delete = secretFile.delete();
    assertTrue(delete);
}
```

The `createSecretFile` will test the creation of our protected pdf file and this predictably works!

The `readAndCopySecretFile` test will check if the file can be read back without using any password and when we do it we get the `InvalidPasswordException` as expected:

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException: Cannot decrypt PDF, the password is incorrect
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.prepareForDecryption(StandardSecurityHandler.java:289)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.prepareDecryption(COSParser.java:1875)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.retrieveTrailer(COSParser.java:300)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:107)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:136)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:466)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:348)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:303)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:246)
    at org.jesperancinha.SecretDocument.readAndCopySecretFile(SecretDocument.java:51)
    at org.jesperancinha.SecretDocumentTest.readAndCopySecretFile(SecretDocumentTest.java:14)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
```

So this already told me that the file is correctly encrypted.

### Reading in a non standard way

Using `readAllBytes` always works. This is will just read everything in the file in a byte form even if it is just gibberish. But I was curious if by any chance, reading the file that way, we would get, somehow the actual text that is in the original file: "This is a test". And for that I created this test:

```
/**
 * Explicitly ignoring warning
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Test
void readInputStream() throws IOException {
    var file = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource(TEST_SECRET_PDF)).getFile();
    String value = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(file)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(value);
    assertFalse(value.contains("This is a test"));
}
```

After running the test we see that we don't get any "This is a test" within all the bytes read from file. I wouldn't be able to quantify how safe is this file after this specific encryption, but I think we can be rest assured that the file is encrypted and so what you are reading from that `readAllBytes` should be just encrypted gibberish since you need the password to turn that gibberish into actual readable text.

You can find this modified example on my test project [here](https://github.com/jesperancinha/jeorg-java-test-drives/tree/main/secret-document).

### Read more

Find out more in the original pdfbox documentation here:

1. [PDFBOX Apache original website](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Comment: Yes but when you are reading bytes from the file you are returning a String:

`String value = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(file)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

The file may have images also so returning a String won't be enough right...?  I want to return bytes from this password protected file over a rest call for caller to convert back into password protected pdf - but after Files.readAllBytes am losing all the encryption unfortunately..

If I try to save the document into ByteArrayOutputStream - doesn't work either(wants me to remove all encryption first) so no solution so far!

Comment: Your question is as I understand specifically concerned about whether your file gets encrypted or not. Following your comment I've added tests that make a copy of an encrypted file using only bytes and try to read the file back using `readAllBytes`. In all cases I  get prompted for a password. Another question is, if the images and/or text are protected enough using this kind of encryption, but this is off scope for this question. Check your code for bugs and please update your versions. This is the only advice that I can give you further at this point with the input you have given.